# Command not found in zsh even though which works

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to run a command:

```
$ xsv
zsh: command not found: xsv
```

But if I try to do:

```
$ which xsv
~/hdd/.cargo/bin/xsv
```

it finds the command. So I think the PATH variable is working correctly. But why zsh is not able to find the command?

Pasting the output asked in the comments:

```
$ emulate zsh -vxc xsv
+(eval):1> xsv
zsh: command not found: xsv
$ type -a xsv
xsv not found
```

Comment: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/4667)

Comment: @glennjackman : Correct, but at least knowing that it is in the PATH, would mean that zsh should at least find _some_ xsv, even if it is shadowed by an alias or function.

Comment: @ln78: It is odd. The only - pretty farfetched  - explanation would be that you have a function named xsv, which locally changes the PATH, and then tries to do a `command xsv`. While this could explain your behaviour, it is an extremely unlikely situtation. Still, for the safe side: What does a `type -a xsv` tell you?

Comment: @In78: Just to rule out other unlikely possibilities: You are doing both - calling xsv and doing the which xsv - from the exactly same shell process (i.e. from the identical command line), not in different terminals, don't you?

Comment: @glennjackman In Zsh, [`which` is a builtin](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-which), which works differently from the external command `which`.

Comment: @ln78 Please do `emulate zsh -vxc xsv` and copy-paste the output into your question.

Comment: @user1934428 I am doing both from the same shell process.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the outputs asked in the comments.

Comment: Well, you should of course have done the `type` in the same process where you run the `xsv` command (i.e. **not** using `zsh xsv`), though I don't believe that this is the reason. Do for instance a `type -a xsv ; xsv` on the command line for a realistic test.

Comment: But at least the `type` command shows that `xsv` is indeed not in your PATH. I guess that `echo =xsv` also shows _xsv not found_. So in this case, you have to fix your PATH.

Comment: What output do you get from `whence -aSv which`?